# Trouble Publishing Quarto Observable Document with External CSV Data on Rpubs

Tags: r, observable, quarto, rpubs

I have created a simple interactive Quarto Observable document that reads data from a CSV file, performs transformations, and generates a plot. The document works perfectly on my local environment. However, when I attempt to publish it on Rpubs using R Studio, I encounter an issue.

Here is the relevant code snippet from my Quarto Observable document where I read the CSV file:

```
LT = FileAttachment("LongTableBar.csv").csv().then(data => {
  // Convert Percentage values to numbers
  data.forEach(d => {
    d.Percentage = parseFloat(d.Percentage);
  });

  // Now you can use the processed data
  return data;
})
```

I make additional transformations and generate a plot in the document:

```
Plot.plot({
  color: {legend: true},
  y: {
    grid: true
  },
  x: { axis: null },
  marks: [
    Plot.ruleY([0]),
    Plot.barY(further_test, {x: "ID", y: "Percentage", sort: {x: "y", reverse: true}, fill: (d) => colorScale(d.intersections)})
  ]
})
```

The document works flawlessly on my local setup, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

However, when I attempt to publish it on Rpubs, I encounter the following issue:

[image]

You can access the published document with the error [here](https://rpubs.com/derek_corcoran/interactive_scaleup_test).

Additionally, I have received the following warning during the publishing process:

```
WARNING] Deprecated: --self-contained. use --embed-resources --standalone
```

I suspect that the issue may be related to the YAML configuration. I attempted to address it by modifying the YAML as follows:

```
title: "Test with some data"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: custom
execute:
  echo: false
  Rendering:
    embed-resources: true
    standalone: true
```

However, the error persists even after making this change. The entire document and associated files are available in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/ObservableTest/).

### Quarto version

I have verified my Quarto version using the following code:

```
quarto::quarto_version()
[1] ‘1.2.335’
```

I appreciate any assistance in identifying and resolving the issue with publishing my Quarto Observable document on Rpubs. Thank you!

Comment: What does that `Rendering` key do? I am not finding anything like this on Quarto documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using the `embed-resources` key under the `execute` and then `Rendering` key, but that's the reason `embed-resources: true` is not generating a standalone file. Instead try using `embed-resources` directly.

```yaml
---
title: "Test with some data"
format: 
  html:
    page-layout: custom
execute:
  echo: false
embed-resources: true
standalone: true
---
```

And look into this [issue #7331 on pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/7331) for details regarding the warning.

Comment: Thanks for that easy solve, I dont know why I did that I was googling stuff and probably got confused on the way